# Why don't MS Dynamics NAV allow import/export of Macros Enabled Word Doc for Word Layout

Tags: vba, ms-word, macros, microsoft-dynamics, navision

I have been trying to import macro enabled word documents in Custom Report Layout of NAV but it does not save it. Rather it saves it as a normal word document (.docx)

So i was wondering why don't microsoft let us import/export Word Macro-Enabled Document (.docm). This would greatly help to do customizations for clients on the word document itself without having to make changes to the standard report dataset. We could make use of VB for the customizations

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would be nice but the reason is for that is that the macro enabled Word file is totally different than the docx. 
In this case Microsoft Word is just a "Report Designer" to create the layout.

And there is an another reason : security. You don't want to allow anyone to be able to import and use "some random" VBA script with an ERP system which handles extremely critical data.

And maybe one more reason : performance. What is the macros is runs for 5 minutes? What if it has unhanded exceptions, infinite loops etc..

Answer (score 0):

The proposed answer is implausible in my opinion.
At first, I always thought, that NAV only supplies the custom XML part in order to fill the content controls of the word document. Therefore, it shouldn't make any difference for NAV, if the Word document is with or without macros. The true reason for this lack of functionality might be the different file extension (docm instead of docx).
Furthermore, security is assured, because **not** anyone can import "some random" VBA code, as this is restricted through user rights management. So the only problem might be to accidentally import malicious code into the NAV database. This is very unlikely, since those Word documents are usually created from the scratch or copied from standard layouts and **not** from dubious internet sources or mail attachements.

Comment: As I supposed earlier, it is only a matter of the file extension.
In NAV 2016 I can save a word layout containing macros (docm - file) into a report (change the predefined docx filter to "all files" in order to import the layout). When I run the report in preview mode, a temporary docx file is created, which causes problems when opened with word. So I saved the report output file to a a docm - extension and could open it in word without any problems...